# No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: python, jenkins, airflow

I'm running Jenkins docker alongside airflow on my local machine. Airflow task intended to trigger already created Jenkins job using JenkinsJobTriggerOperator fails with No crumb included error. JenkinsJobTriggerOperator seems to be trying to fetch the crumb implicitly and failing.

Able to trigger the said job from local by supplying crumb. I checked the connectivity between the airflow worker container and Jenkins container. I was also successful in triggering the job by bashing into the airflow worker. Tweaked the Jenkins connection configuration through airflow API. No luck.

```
job_trigger_task = JenkinsJobTriggerOperator(
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    task_id="job_trigger_task",
    job_name="my_jenkins_job",
    parameters={'token':'xxxxxxxx',
                'param_a':145754,
                'param_b':'abc',
                'param_c':'a12423'},  
    # Preconfigered connection
    jenkins_connection_id="local_jenkins"
)
```

Airflow logs below:

```
{jenkins_job_trigger_operator.py:210} INFO - Triggering the job my_jenkins_job on the jenkins : local_jenkins with the parameters : {'param_a':145754, 'param_b':'abc','param_c':'a12423'}

{logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - {base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: id: local_jenkins. Host: jenkins_webserver, Port: 8080, Schema: None, Login: "myjenkinsuser", Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: {}

{jenkins_hook.py:44} INFO - Trying to connect to http://jenkins_webserver:8080

{models.py:1788} ERROR - Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [403]: No valid crumb was included in the request
```

**Note:** jenkins_webserver is the Jenkins container name

I tried multiple variants for host_name while configuring connection like:

Host: local_ip
Host: localhost
Host: jenkins_container_name
Host: Jenkins container's IP address

CSRF Protection is enabled in my Jenkins deployment. Disabling it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use an [API token](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) to trigger the job instead of username/password. This [will not require crumb if using Jenkins 2.96+](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection).